# Is it possible to pass an argument to wasm-opt with clang

Tags: clang, webassembly

I'm trying to compile a wasm binary with multivalue and O3, however, I keep getting `[wasm-validator error in module] unexpected false: Imported multivalue function requires multivalue [--enable-multivalue]`.

The current flags that I'm using are `--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm -O3 -nostdlib -funroll-loops -Wall -Wno-comment -mllvm -polly -mmultivalue -Xclang -target-abi -Xclang experimental-mv -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -s -Wl,--export-dynamic,--allow-undefined,--gc-sections`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sadly there is no way (today) to modify the wasm-opt command line that clang uses.

This seems like a bug in llvm and really the target-features section of binary should contains `multivalue`, which should then enable it automatically in wasm-opt.  Could you open an llvm bug about this?

For now your best bet might be to run clang without wasm-opt in your PATH.